# If the register size and the address bus are equal so do we need those segementation register to segment our memory?

Tags: memory-management, memory-hardware

In 8086, as i know we need those segementation register to segment our memory because the address bus is 20 bit and register size is 16. So, If the register size and the address bus are equal and we can store all possible physical addresses in our registers like 80386 microprocessor, do we need those segementation register to segment our memory or even do we need to segment our memory ? **why if yes and why if no**